# How do I randomize without repetion in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sample

With a data frame, how do I randomize it so that it is truly mixed up? Such that the rows that were beside each other in the original table are not together anymore.

For example with this table.

```
U         A         B         C
0  1.438161 -0.210454         0
1 -0.283780 -0.371773         0
2  0.552564 -0.610548         0
3  1.931332  0.649179         1
4  1.656010 -1.373263         1
5  0.142682 -0.657849         1
6  1.754264 -0.610548         0
7  1.341232  0.649179         0
8  1.656010 -1.373263         0
9  0.944862 -0.657849         0
```

How do I make so that it looks something like this? (By randomizing)

```
U         A         B         C
1 -0.283780 -0.371773         0
3  1.931332  0.649179         1
0  1.438161 -0.210454         0
4  1.656010 -1.373263         1
8  1.656010 -1.373263         0
6  1.754264 -0.610548         0
2  0.552564 -0.610548         0
7  1.341232  0.649179         0
9  0.944862 -0.657849         0
5  0.142682 -0.657849         1
```

Notice that the index numbers in the second table do not have any values that either goes up or goes down in consecutive order (ie, no 6, 7 or 4,3)

Comment: > "Such that the rows that were beside each other in the original table are not together anymore"

That's not exactly random though. Mind if I ask what your end goal is? Perhaps we might be able to suggest a better thing that helps you accomplish what you want

Comment: Try `df = df.sample(frac=1.)`

Comment: My end goal is to have a data frame where there is a different data frame every time I run the code but the rows in the table cannot be beside each other. So II said randomize it as the final dataframe has to be different everytime I run the code

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need (truly random means rows that were together may still be together after however):

```
df.sample(frac=1)
```

`frac` is the fraction of results to return, 1 means all.

More docs here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html